# Remove duplicate element from array by checking specific key

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing objects. Where I need to check each object with a specific value for key and remove the object with the same value..

```
 var data = [  
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":0.14,
      "USERID":"46473",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":1,
      "VALUE":0.39,
      "USERID":"46477",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":2
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":1,
      "VALUE":0.39,
      "USERID":"46475",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":2
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":1,
      "VALUE":0.39,
      "USERID":"46479",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":2
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":0.94,
      "USERID":"46471",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":2.42,
      "USERID":"46474",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":4.78,
      "USERID":"46472",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   }
]
```

I need in below format

```
var outdata = [  
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":0.14,
      "USERID":"46473",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":1,
      "VALUE":0.39,
      "USERID":"46477",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":2
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":0.94,
      "USERID":"46471",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":2.42,
      "USERID":"46474",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   },
   {  
      "XPOS":0,
      "VALUE":4.78,
      "USERID":"46472",
      "MORE_USER_COUNT":1
   }
]
```

Comment: JSON is a string-based serialization format for exchanging information. This question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/tzayzL0t/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrData = [
    {
        "XPOS": 0,
        "VALUE": 0.14,
        "USERID": "46473",
        "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
    },
    {
        "XPOS": 1,
        "VALUE": 0.39,
        "USERID": "46477",
        "MORE_USER_COUNT": 2
    },
    {
        "XPOS": 1,
        "VALUE": 0.39,
        "USERID": "46475",
        "MORE_USER_COUNT": 2
    },
    {
        "XPOS": 1,
        "VALUE": 0.39,
        "USERID": "46479",
        "MORE_USER_COUNT": 2
    },
    {
        "XPOS": 0,
        "VALUE": 0.94,
        "USERID": "46471",
        "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
    },
    {
        "XPOS": 0,
        "VALUE": 2.42,
        "USERID": "46474",
        "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
    },
    {
        "XPOS": 0,
        "VALUE": 4.78,
        "USERID": "46472",
        "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
    }
];
document.getElementById("real_data").appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(arrData, null, "\t")));

// FUNCTION TO REMOVE DUPLICATE ELEMENT BASED ON KEY
function removeDuplicate() {
    arrData.forEach(function (objElement1, intIndex1) {
        arrData.forEach(function (objElement2, intIndex2) {
            if (intIndex1 !== intIndex2 && objElement1.XPOS === objElement2.XPOS && objElement1.VALUE === objElement2.VALUE)
            {
                // REMOVE ARRAY ELEMENT
                arrData.splice(intIndex2, 1);
            }
        });
    });
}
removeDuplicate() ;


document.getElementById("expected_data").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("expected_data").appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(arrData, null, 4)));
```

```css
#real_data,
#expected_data {
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="real_data"></div>
  <hr/>
  <div id="expected_data"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to remove objects from the data array that have duplicate "VALUE" values. If this is the case, you should be able to create a temp array and push objects from the original array to the temp array if a match doesn't already exist in the temp array.

The problem will be figuring out *which* of the objects with the duplicate value you want to keep. It's not clear what the criteria are.

```
var original_values = [{
  "XPOS": 0,
  "VALUE": 0.14,
  "USERID": "46473",
  "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
}, {
  "XPOS": 1,
  "VALUE": 0.39,
  "USERID": "46477",
  "MORE_USER_COUNT": 2
}, {
  "XPOS": 1,
  "VALUE": 0.39,
  "USERID": "46475",
  "MORE_USER_COUNT": 2
}, {
  "XPOS": 1,
  "VALUE": 0.39,
  "USERID": "46479",
  "MORE_USER_COUNT": 2
}, {
  "XPOS": 0,
  "VALUE": 0.94,
  "USERID": "46471",
  "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
}, {
  "XPOS": 0,
  "VALUE": 2.42,
  "USERID": "46474",
  "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
}, {
  "XPOS": 0,
  "VALUE": 4.78,
  "USERID": "46472",
  "MORE_USER_COUNT": 1
}];

var pruned_values = [];

function pruneArray(array, searchKey) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var theValue = array[i][searchKey];
    if (!checkForDuplicates(pruned_values, searchKey, theValue)) {
      pruned_values.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  original_values = pruned_values;
}

function checkForDuplicates(array, searchKey, searchValue) {
  var foundDuplicate = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][searchKey] === searchValue) {
      foundDuplicate = true;
    }
  }
  return foundDuplicate;
}

pruneArray(original_values, "VALUE");
```